# How to go about this layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

I am new to React and having trouble with the positioning components. I have attached an image of the desired layout. ,  and the side  are common for all the pages. How do I go about this layout? Should I use grid?

I tried using the side div as a separate component but the contents of the div changes for every page and I am not sure how to update its contents with respect to the current page.[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEzLe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i am giving you generic code first use the layout in App and than use the CSS. you can use bootstrap, tailwind or another styling framework as well  where you can layout your template , and use the router for using this template ..

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px; /* Adjust 200px to your desired sidebar width */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / 3; /* Spanning full width */
  background-color: #eee;
}

.body {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 4; /* Spanning from top to bottom */
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import './Layout.css'; // Assuming you saved the CSS in a file named Layout.css

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="navbar">Navbar</div>
      <div className="body">Body</div>
      <div className="footer">Footer</div>
      <div className="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```